# Strange issue with Date.Parse / ParseExact not altering date (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, parsing, date

I have a bit of a head scratcher with the Date.Parse /ParseExact functionality in VB.
To surmise, I have an ASP.Net 4.0 app, on one of the pages there is a calendar control which the user chooses a date and time, these are fed into a string (strReqDeadline) which takes the following European / UK date time format: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff

So for example the contents of strReqDeadline would be: 29/03/2013 16:30:00.000

I then need to insert this into a SQL datetime column, so obviously it needs converted from UK to the US/datetime format. I've been attempting to do this with Date.Parse and Date.ParseExact with no success. The following *should* work according to the research I've done:

```
strReqDeadline = "29/03/2013 16:30:00.000"
Dim usDate = As Date = Date.ParseExact(strReqDeadline, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

However, what actually happens at runtime is bizzare, the Date.ParseExact function trims off the fractal seconds from the time (as far as I can see it **shouldn't** be doing this because the filter specifies .fff), and otherwise leaves the entire string completely unchanged. 
So, if the value of usDate is output, it appears as follows: **29/03/2013 16:30:00**

What it *should* contain is datetime: **3/29/2013 4:30PM**

The really strange thing is if I put a watch on usDate and start the app, in the development environment its value shows as **#3/29/2013 4:30PM#**, both in the watch list and when hovered over in the source window, but any form of output displays the original string, just minus the fractions of second, and doesn't convert to datetime.

From what I read the 'InvariantCulture' specification should negate any locale specific issues with output, but just in case this were the issue I also tried specifying an explicit local culture with  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")  (tried fr-FR too), but this makes no difference. The Windows regional settings on both the client and server are set to UK if this bears any relevance.

Maybe I'm missing something very obvious but I just can't see why I'm getting this output, Date.ParseExact doesn't throw any exceptions or complain about the string not being recognised, but I'm struggling to understand why it just removes the fraction seconds and does nothing else, especially since the input spring matches the specified mask exactly.

I'd be very interested to hear if anyone else has experienced an odd issue like this and what you did with it!

Thanks :)

EDIT: Full code with SQL section is as follows:

```
strReqDeadline = "29/03/2013 16:30:00.000"    
Dim usDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(strReqDeadline, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

'SQL
Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=XXXXX;initial catalog=YYYYY;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()

cmd.Connection = con

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Requests (ReqOwnerID, ReqDeadline, ReqStatus)" _
& "VALUES ('" & UserID & "', '" & usDate & "', '1')"

con.Open()
Dim NewReqID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

con.Close()
```

'

Comment: If you're going to store this date in the Sql date column, why convert it to string first?

Comment: Unfortunately it's being output as string by the custom calendar control added by someone previously. I'm going to look into replacing this with something native that can handle the date type but for now I just need to get it tidied up and running. You're completely correct though, a pointless task! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it you thin it is not working?  These are **all** the same underlying date/time:

```
29/03/2013 16:30:00.000

29/03/2013 16:30:00

3/29/2013 4:00PM
```

You cannot rely on what hovering over a non-string variable shows to determine its inner value.  All you are seeing is the evaluation of `ToString()`.  If you want a String to show the fractions seconds, then you need to call `ToString()` and specify the format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff".  By default a DateTime type if not going to show your fractions seconds when you convert to a `String`.

---

If you are not using parameters (and you should be) then your final SQL statement after injecting the DateTime would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTableWithDate
   (column1
   ,column2
   ,MyDateCol)
VALUES 
   ('a'
   ,'b'
   ,'20130329 16:30:00.557')
```

---

As I mentioned before, a `Date` datatype is not String.  It's an object (or a rather a DateTime structure, by I digress).  You **must** call the correct `ToString()` meth0d.

Try using this withing your SQL string:

```
& "VALUES ('" & UserID & "', '" & usDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff") & "', '1')"
```

Of course, there is little point converting a string to Date object to immediately convert it back to a string again, but this code should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, the string thing explains the fractal seconds being truncated. The reason I think its not working correctly though is when I attempt to insert the contents of usDate into a SQL datetime column, the server throws a 'the conversion of a varchar datatype to datetime failed'. When I manually output the contents of the SQL Insert string, usDate shows as '29/03/2013 16:30:00' - should it not be in Datetime format (i.e M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss) by this point if Date.ParseExact has processed it?

Comment: Keeping the fractal seconds is not essential however if I omit them in the filter and just have dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss  then the FormatException 'String not recognised as a valid DateTime' is thrown, so I just kept them in. If there's a way to forego them and successfully convert to datetime without error I'd be happy to do that.

Comment: You need to post the SQL related code, that is where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention, the SQL error I mentioned in my first comment is actually 'The conversion to a datetime datatype resulted in an out of range value' (i.e its getting the date string still in UK format), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please post the code that does the SQL insert/update.  You are either incorrectly specifying a parameter type or if you are inlining your date arg into a SQL string then you are calling an incorrect version of `ToString()`.  Again, show your code.

Comment: Hi, have edited the original post to show the SQL code, which is relatively simple. If I output cmd.commandtext (for example by response.writing it to as Msgbox), then the value of usDate shows as 29/03/2013 16:30:00 - do you think I need to .ToString it here?

Comment: Yes, that output is from using the default `ToString()` method of the date object, which is automatically called when you concat it with another string.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Please let me know if that new version of ToString in my revised answer fails to work.

Comment: Hi, adding the .ToString with the filter you suggested works perfectly, thank you!  I don't know how I managed to miss that requirement out, I guess my mistake was expecting a DateTime object to behave like a normal string without any conversion, it seems so obvious now, thank you again. Regarding your comment about going String->Datetime->String, I agree it's a bit cumbersome, I'll try and implement a more elegant solution once everything else is tidied up :)

Comment: @CiaránReilly - Why convert the date to a string in the first place?  Doesn't the calendar control return a date already? If your column in your database is of type datetime, then skip the conversion to string and insert the date directly.

Answer (score 2):

usDate is an object of type DateTime, and it appears to be storing the correct value. When you are inspecting it, you are seeing a string representation of that datetime value. It doesn't contain either 29/03/2013 16:30:00 or 3/29/2013 4:30PM, those are just two valid representations of what it contains.

You say

> any form of output displays the original string

This is not true. In fact you have control over how it is output when you call ToString(), where a format can be specified

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and explains the discrepency between the values displayed by the debug output and app itself. Is it advisable to use .ToString when inserting the object into the SQL query string, or is it sufficient to just put the object name itself (i.e usDate)#

Comment: It's advisable to be using a type safe method of inserting the value into SQL, such as adding it as a parameter as tcarvin mentioned. That way you don't need to worry about the format as you are giving the database the correct type which it knows how to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into parameterizing the queries as tcarvin and yourself have suggested, its much tidier and should prevent this kind of scenario in future, another helpful pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing looks correct i.e. using Date.ParseExact to convert a date in UK format to a Date type. The issue you are having is that when it displays this as a string it is displaying it in your local culture (the debugger appears to  always want to display in US format), but the Date you have set is correct.